# How to guard against Illegal characters in path in Uri

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an old site that is running on .net 4 that I unfortunately cannot update. 
 So I'm stuck with whatever .net 4 has to offer.  There is error handling built into the global.asax.cs to handle any exceptions that occur on the site.  One that keeps coming up is *Illegal characters in path*.  When I look at the url that's generating this error it's something like...

```
http://www.thisdumbsite.com/folder/page.aspx" class="src_res
```

So, apparently somewhere there's a malformed link.  I've tried checking the site for this link and cannot find it so the next thing I want to do is at least disregard any alerts that the global error handling is sending to me when these are processed.  The problem is that I can't seem to get the url without causing the exception to occur.  I tried something like this.

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("class=%22src_res")) { 
//do error handling and email me
}
```

This doesn't work because the AbsoluteUri is what is throwing the exception.  Is there another way to get the url without triggering the exception?  Thanks.

Comment: `try {...} catch {...}`
alternative is to go over the headers themself

Comment: Trying to ignore the URL is not the correct way to solve the problem. It hides the problem which is even worse, and the URL will still be broken. You're saying that you cannot find `src_res` in your entire project? Try to log the referrer page to at least see what page contains that link, then you can look for the relevant code for the URL on that page.

Comment: It's not in the web site.  Already tried tracking the referrer but it keeps coming up null.

Comment: Perhaps it is coming from the database or another data source? Try looking for it there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
try{
    var uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    //works so valid URI, either check it here or continue error handling.
}
catch{
//suppress
}
```